# woocommerce shortcode for products in brand and category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I want to display all products that are in specific category and brand. For example I have category `boiler` and brand `Ariston`. Is there any way to display only Ariston's boilers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `[products]` if your brand is under the category as well then follow the code below:

```php
[products category="Ariston,boiler" cat_operator="AND"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$loop = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order'   => 'DESC',
                'category_name' => 'Ariston'
            )
        );
```

Then, you can read the loop:

```
 <?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            
         <div>
             <?php echo get_the_title(); ?> - <?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
         </div>

         <?php endwhile; ?>
```

And then, you can use the result in the way you want.

I hope I have made myself understand.

Comment: yeah, but I need only boilers, not everything from Ariston

Comment: How do you use the “brand” in your shop? another category type? attributes? variations?

Comment: As I said, I need a shortcode, not a loop.